# Getting JointJS to work as a package in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, jointjs

I found this repo on github that is a package for meteor-jointjs

https://github.com/kidovate/meteor-joint

however I can't get it to work... I've modified the package.js

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {

api.use('jquery', 'client');
api.use('underscore', 'client');
// api.use('lodash', 'client');
// api.use('backbone', 'client');

api.export('joint', 'client');

api.add_files(['lib/jquery.js','lib/lodash.js','lib/backbone.js'], 'client');
api.add_files(['joint.js', 'joint.css'], 'client');
```

});

I added 'libs' folder - which I got form the JointJS bower install

I've also modified the 'joint.js' file so that the

// Global namespace.

```
var joint = {
```

is now:

```
joint = {
```

so that the 'joint' variable is now globally accessible in meteor - as per the instructions:
in this tutorial:

https://github.com/awwx/misc/wiki/Packaging-Existing-Libraries-for-Meteor

When I try to access the page I get this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined    (joint.js: 8253)
```

the line of code thats a problem is:

```
return client ? _.bind(raf, window) : raf;
```

the problem being that "_" is not undefined -> no idea how to fix this...

Comment: Are you using any meteor package that globally provides the `require` function?

Comment: Mmmm I was using famono, but it was complaining about providing the related packages - perhaps if I can get that sorted out it could work ... do you have any other suggestion for a package that provides `require` ?

Comment: Ok I found your package on atmosphere: [define](http://atmospherejs.com/package/define) ;) I'll give it a try ...

Comment: I assume you know that `_` is likely an underscore library reference.  Did you ever get jointjs working with meteor?

Comment: Nope I didn't, tried a lot but in the ended I used www.fame.us to render. Although now that I have some time I might go back and have another look... yes the "_" is supposed to be from underscore. I included underscore (line 3: "api.use('underscore', 'client');") but didn't seem to help. Maybe I did it wrong?